# Bat'ник проверка группы запустивщего юзера

Tags: bat, cmd

Суть задачи такова: запустить bat'ник, в нем проверка: если данный юзер входит в определенную группу, то запустить скрипт `blabla.vbs:`.

Никогда не писал команд, и сейчас особо не получается. Пока вот так, но не работает:

```
CLS
@ECHO OFF
CHCP 1251
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET uname = %username%
SET localgroup = Администратор
SET vbspath = D:\prj\bat\blabla.txt
SET output = output.bat

NET USER %uname% > output.bat

for /f %%a in ('type output.bat') do (echo %%a | findstr /b %localgroup%)
```

имхо, предположительно должно работать так: получили имя юзера, выполнили NET USER %username%, записали в файл, а потом в файле просто ищем подстроку с нужным нам названием группы localgroup, если таковая есть - запускаем vbs скрип.  Вот самое последнее хз как написать, синтаксиса не знаю.

Comment: Неужели никто не писал команд?(

Comment: А это нетривиальная задача для батника, я думаю здесь, нужно расширение powershell, которое как раз расширяет администрирование из командной строки. Вот, например, то, что вам нужно:   http://www.sysengineering.ru/blog/powershell-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLS
@ECHO OFF
CHCP 1251
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET uname=%username%
SET localgroup=Users2
SET vbspath=D:\prj\bat\blabla.txt
SET output=output.bat
SET result=

NET USER %uname% > output.bat

for /f %%i in ('FINDSTR /L "%localgroup%" %output%') do (set result=%%i)
if not "!result!"=="" ( 
    echo %vbspath%
) else (
    echo "Совпадений нет"
)
```

Не даю гарантии, что будет с русскими буквами работать.

Comment: Спасибо @lampa с кириллицей тоже отработал, буду продолжать тестировать.